# matlab find substring in cell array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

I try to find arrays in my cell which have to part 'HA' in their names. I found a function here but it does not work for my problem.
My cell looks like this:

```
'HA1'   'HA1'   'HA1'   'HA1'   'HA1'
'HA2'   'HA2'   'HA2'   'HA2'   'HA2'
'HA3'   'HA3'   'HA3'   'HA3'   'HA3'
'HA4'   'HA4'   'HA4'   'HA4'   'HA4'
'HA5'   'HA5'   'HA5'   'HA5'   'HA5'
'HA6'   'HA6'   'HA6'   'HA6'   'HA6'
'HA7'   'HA7'   'HA7'   'HA7'   'HA7'
'HA8'   'WA1'   'WA1'   'WA1'   'WA1'
'HA9'   'WA2'   'WA2'   'WA2'   'WA2'
'HA10'  'WA3'   'WA3'   'WA3'   'WA3'
'HA11'  'WA4'   'WA4'   'WA4'   'WA4'
'DA1'   'WA5'   'WA5'   'WA5'   'WA5'
'DA2'   []  []  []  'WA6'
'DA3'   []  []  []  'WA7'
'DA4'   []  []  []  'WA8'
'DA5'   []  []  []  'WA9'
'DA6'   []  []  []  'WA10'
[]  []  []  []  'WA11'
[]  []  []  []  'WA12'
```

I tried this function:

```
x = 'HA';
y = cellArray;
substrfind = @(x,y) ~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(y,x));
logicalArray = substrfind(x,y);
```

Im supposed to get a logical array as output which is really useful for my problem. But instead I get this error message:
" If any of the input arguments are cell arrays, the first must be a cell array of strings and the second must be a character array."

I do not understand what the error is because the first input y is a cell array and the second x a character.

I hope you guys can help me with my problem!
Thank you in anticipation!
Best regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose `C` is your cell array. Then one way to do what you want would be this:

```
>> C(cellfun('isempty', C)) = {''};
>> logicalArray = ~cellfun('isempty', strfind(C, 'HA'))
```

`strfind` does not accept cell arrays of which some values are not strings. Your cell array happens to have empty values, but of the *wrong kind* -- `[]` is `double`, not `char`. That is the reason you get that error.

So, I simply replace every empty `double` with the empty char (`''`), and then use `strfind`.

Another way around this problem:

```
>> logicalArray = cellfun(@(x)~isempty(strfind(x,'HA')), C)
```

but that is a lot slower.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot! I did not examine the empty values. Next time I won't forget!