# Find substring in cell array of numbers and strings

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array consisting of numbers, strings, and empty arrays.  I want to find the position (linear or indexed) of all cells containing a string in which a certain substring of interest appears.

```
mixedCellArray = {
   'adpo' 2134  []
   0 [] 'daesad'
   'xxxxx' 'dp' 'dpdpd'
}
```

If the substring of interest is 'dp', then I should get the indices for three cells.

The only solutions I can find work when the cell array contains only strings:

- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2015-find-index-of-cells-containing-my-string
- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/255090

One work-around is to find all cells not containing strings, and fill them with '', as hinted by [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931954/matlab-find-substring-in-cell-array).  Unfortunately, my approach requires a variation of that solution, probably something like `cellfun('ischar',mixedCellArray)`.  This causes the error:

```
Error using cellfun
Unknown option.
```

Thanks for any suggestions on how to figure out the error.

I've posted this to [usenet](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/gpylYTARWv8)

EDUCATIONAL AFTERNOTE: For those who don't have Matlab at home, and end up bouncing back and forth between Matlab and Octave.  I asked above why `cellfun` doesn't accept `'ischar'` as its first argument.  The answer turns out to be that the argument must be a function handle in Matlab, so you really need to pass `@ischar`.  There are some functions whose names can be passed as strings, for backward compatibility, but `ischar` is not one of them.

Comment: See: [timing results](https://gist.github.com/sco1/2ae53cb243a371ada5186965db7e8272). Note the performance disadvantage of tweet-style one line coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this one-liner:

```
>> mixedCellArray = {'adpo' 2134  []; 0 [] 'daesad'; 'xxxxx' 'dp' 'dpdpd'};
>> index = cellfun(@(c) ischar(c) && ~isempty(strfind(c, 'dp')), mixedCellArray)

index =

  3×3 logical array

   1   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   1   1
```

You *could* get by without the `ischar(c) && ...`, but you will likely want to keep it there since [`strfind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) will implicitly convert any numeric values/arrays into their equivalent ASCII characters to do the comparison. That means you could get false positives, as in this example:

```
>> C = {65, 'A'; 'BAD' [66 65 68]}  % Note there's a vector in there

C =

  2×2 cell array

    [ 65]    'A'         
    'BAD'    [1×3 double]

>> index = cellfun(@(c) ~isempty(strfind(c, 'A')), C)  % Removed ischar(c) &&

index =

  2×2 logical array

   1   1                % They all match!
   1   1
```

Comment: Wow. That's educational.  I need to go back into my code and build in that error trapping.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a loop, testing with [`ischar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ischar.html) and [`contains`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contains.html) (added in R2016b). The various `*fun`s are basically loops and, in general, do not offer any performance advantage over the explicit loop.

```
mixedCellArray = {'adpo' 2134  []; 0 [] 'daesad'; 'xxxxx' 'dp' 'dpdpd'};
querystr = 'dp';

test = false(size(mixedCellArray));
for ii = 1:numel(mixedCellArray)
    if ischar(mixedCellArray{ii})
        test(ii) = contains(mixedCellArray{ii}, querystr);
    end
end
```

Which returns:

```
test =

  3×3 logical array

   1   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   1   1
```

Edit:

If you don't have a MATLAB version with `contains` you can substitute a [regex](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html):

```
test(ii) = ~isempty(regexp(mixedCellArray{ii}, querystr, 'once'));
```

Comment: `strfind` instead of `regexp` is simpler. Don't encourage using `regexp` where simpler specializations exist!

Comment: @Naveh Do you have a *real* reason to recommend `strfind` over `regexp`? "is simpler" is a really dumb reason not to recommend a more powerful function; certainly not a profound multiple upvote-worthy comment one. The syntax isn't even any different: `regexp(mixedCellArray{ii}, querystr)` vs. `strfind(mixedCellArray{ii}, querystr)`. Yippee... What exactly is the gain?

Comment: Perhaps my comment was too simple :) The reasoning behind using `regexp` specializations (`strfind, strtrim, strrep` etc) instead of `regexp` itself is readability. My rule of thumb is to only use `regexp` where no fitting specialization exists. What we want to do is find a substring, so we use `strfind`. It _is_ simpler to understand, which is why I advocate this.

Comment: Naveh, excaza, I want to thank you both for sharing your knowledge of Matlab features for solving this problem.  However, I exhort both of you to respect the different merits of your answers.  I find them both very educational.  Simplicity has a great deal of merit, and for that, I thank Naveh. However, I know that all too soon, I will need to move regular expressions, and I appreciate the gateway code for me to do that, excaza.

Comment: @user36800 You should really check out the timing results mentioned in [this comment](https://gist.github.com/sco1/2ae53cb243a371ada5186965db7e8272). One liners are typically less legible, more error prone, and slower than explicitly using a loop which MATLAB is able to accelerate naturally.

Comment: I was speaking from a personal perspective.  When I see a one-liner, I treat it as an idiomatic atom of code, where specific parameters are supplied at certain points in the code.  If necessary, one can even write a wrapper around it to streamline the calling protocol.  I don't necessarily pull apart the code cognitively and keep in mind how the moving pieces interact (though I often do that for fun).  It's harder to view a block of multi-line code the same way.  More variables and flow control structures to keep track of. There are cases where I do the latter. Both approaches are good.

Comment: Oh, BTW, corporate firewall prevents me from following the link about the comment on one liners being less legible, but I hope my description of my personal perspective is understandable.

Comment: @user36800 `cellfun` is an order of magnitude slower and unnecessarily obfuscated.

Answer (score 2):

```
z=cellfun(@(x)strfind(x,'dp'),mixedCellArray,'un',0);
idx=cellfun(@(x)x>0,z,'un',0);
find(~cellfun(@isempty,idx))
```

Comment: Thanks, Purushottama.  That seems to be similar to the approach proposed on usenet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution from the usenet link in my original post:

```
>> mixedCellArray = {
         'adpo' 2134  []
         0 [] 'daesad'
         'xxxxx' 'dp' 'dpdpd'
      }

mixedCellArray =
    'adpo'     [2134]          []
    [    0]        []    'daesad'
    'xxxxx'    'dp'      'dpdpd'

>> ~cellfun( @isempty , ...
             cellfun( @(x)strfind(x,'dp') , ...
                      mixedCellArray , ...
                      'uniform',0) ...
           )

ans =
     1     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     1     1
```

The inner `cellfun` is able to apply `strfind` to even numerical cells because, I presume, Matlab treats numerical arrays and strings the same way.  A string is just an array of numbers representing the character codes.  The outer `cellfun` identifies all cells for which the inner `cellfun` found a match, and the prefix tilde turns that into all cells for which there was NO match.

Thanks to dpb.